# Bluemix Flask API Call Timeout

Tags: python, flask, ibm-cloud

I have an API written with python flask running on Bluemix. Whenever I send it a request and the API takes more than 120 seconds to respond it times out. It does not return anything and it returns the following error: `500 Error: Failed to establish a backside connection`.

I need it to be able to process longer requests as well. Is there any way to extend the timeout value or is there a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

All Bluemix traffic goes through the IBM WebSphere® DataPower® SOA Appliances, which provide reverse proxy, SSL termination, and load balancing functions. For security reasons DataPower closes inactive connections after 2 minutes.

This is not configurable (as it affects all Bluemix users), so the only solution for your scenario is to change your program to make sure the connection is not idle for more than 2 minutes.